# Detecting overlapping components in an image/label

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I am trying to solve the problem of detecting partially or fully overlapping components in an image. The components can be text, barcodes, QR codes, rectangle boundaries etc.

See the images below for better understanding of the problem.

Below label/image doesn't have any overlappings:

[image: Normal Label]

Below label/image has many overlappings:

[image: Overlapping Components in the Label]

My first thoughts are finding the four corner coordinates of each individual component. Then the problem reduces to finding if any two components(rectangles) out of all the components(rectangles) overlap or not.

But I'm clueless how to find the coordinates of each individual component from the image. Also the above approach fails if we have fully overlapping component printed inside another component. Is there any better way to solve the problem?